# Redirecting HTTPS -> HTTPS on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static website w/ S3 + Route53 + Cloudfront set up. I am successfully able to do the following redirects:

http://example.com -> https://example.com

http://www.example.com -> https://example.com

https://example.com -> https://example.com (no redirect, but loads)

However, I see the following behavior:

https://www.example.com -> page never loads

Is there a way to make
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com ?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  If not I may add a bounty to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are multiple ways to do what you need. 
Are you trying to just make DNS records?

```
127.0.0.1 A example.com
127.0.0.1 A www.example.com
```

OR

```
127.0.0.1 A example.com
www.example.com CNAME example.com
```

There is a way to achieve what you mentioned using nginx or apache configuraion to run 301 requests for redirection. This is what you probably already achieved. Similar to https://thisinterestsme.com/php-forcing-https-over-http/

The problem might be related to the SSL certificate, it is crucial for HTTPS to display site requested, and not the one redirected from. Wildcard SSL might work with *.example.com, which will cover www.example.com.

Comment: I am not running nginx or apache - this is a static site hosted on S3

Answer (score 0):

I would just include the following DNS record in your Route53 configuration:

```
www IN CNAME example.com.
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but this only works if someone is using route53.  We only have the website on amazon so we don't use route53.

Comment: You can add this configuration to your DNS server wherever it is. Certainly it doesn't have to be route53.